# Is there a way to replace all photos to others from a folder on Visua Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

[image: Is there a way to replace all photos to others from a folder on Visual Studio Code?]

Is there a way to replace all photos from my code to others from a folder on Visual Studio Code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Here is the proof that the solutions works.**

[image: Proof that I am the boss]

At the end, you can.

Then just use Copilot to get the following pattern: until 57...

[image: sigo padreando]

[image: Hire lazy ones, get the job done and fast Quote by Bill Gates]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can,

Start by typing

```
"X* "
```

at the beginning, in the middle you type the name of the first photo in the folder you want to place, and at the end you type

```
" *Y"
```

Then,
What it will do, is to replace

```
"X* "
```

by the beginning of the path:

```
"https://github.com/sushi-js/sushis-demo/blob/main/src/common/components/elements/02%20Body/11%20CaseStudies"
```

and

```
" *Y"
```

by

```
".png?raw=true"
```

Only the first 4 names will be typed by hand.

```
/* Hello Copilot */

X* adidas *Y
X* agusti-torello-mata *Y
X* alfapar *Y
X* audi *Y
```

Github copilot detects it, and gives you the correct suggestion.

```
/* Hello Copilot */

X* adidas *Y
X* agusti-torello-mata *Y
X* alfapar *Y
*X* audi *Y* <-- The suggestion is the same as the sidebar photos from my directory.
```

[image: Github Copilot Helps you to replace mass photos]

Don't stop tabbing like there's no tomorrow.

and you're done.

Answer (score 0):

3 more ways to avoid visual studio code explicitly prohibit photo replacement solutions that works inside VS Code

1. With Bash terminal on VS Code, and command tree
2. With Python terminal on VS Code, do a mini executable to get all paths from the photos
3. With data fetch request xml to github folder on a small folder, create a small component to print the paths

Then go to VS Code and copy paste

Answer (score 0):

And the most easiest way ever
Control Right click on photos:
**[image: Copy paths]**

Copy paths, and paste, bye bye solved.

[image: paths]